# Sibling Functional Components communication in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have following code

[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-voice-3yu3e)

I have "App" component which one have 2 sibling components: "First" component and "Second" component.

```
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
           <First />
           <Second />
       </div>
      );
    }
```

In my "First"  component I have button, on click it should change "Second" component text style

```
    function First() {
      const myFunction(){
        let myStyle = document.getElementById("myStyle");
        myStyle.style.color = "red";
        myStyle.style.fontSize = "20px";
        myStyle.style.letterSpacing = "5px";
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="button" value="Click" onClick={myFunction} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default First;
```

I know I write  wrong code for this case, but can you please help me to rewrite this code in right way?

Comment: `useImperativeHandle` hook

Comment: @k-wasilewski can you help me please to use that hook in code? ... I read something in documentation and look some examples but didn't catch how to change  in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forwardRef` to achieve this https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bush-wuxn0

```
// App.js

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import First from "./Components/First";
import Second from "./Components/Second";
export default function App() {
  const [secondTextEl, setSecondTextEl] = React.useState(null);

  const textRef = React.useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setSecondTextEl(node);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <First secondText={secondTextEl} />
      <Second ref={textRef} />
    </div>
  );
}


// First.jsx

import React from "react";

function First({ secondText }) {
  function myFunction(props) {
    secondText.style.color = "red";
    secondText.style.fontSize = "20px";
    secondText.style.letterSpacing = "5px";
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Click" onClick={myFunction} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default First;

// Second.jsx

import React from "react";

function Second(props, ref) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref} id="myStyle">
        Change my style
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default React.forwardRef(Second);
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I write as you show I have error like: Cannot read property 'style' of null